# NumbersTable() function in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Our chief database programmer is out this week on vacation and I'm stuck.

I have a view that's getting created that includes the following sub-query:

```
select cast(cast(getdate() + i as date) as datetime) DATEVALUE 
from NumbersTable(1,100,1)
```

I have no idea what this does, and when I try to run it inside of Squirrel, I get:

```
Error: Procedure or function NumbersTable has too many arguments specified.
SQLState:  37000
ErrorCode: 8144
```

Here are the function creates for NumbersTable:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION NumbersTable (
  @fromNumber int,
  @toNumber int,
  @byStep int
) RETURNS TABLE
RETURN (

WITH CTE_NumbersTable AS (
  SELECT @fromNumber AS i
  UNION ALL
  SELECT i + @byStep
  FROM CTE_NumbersTable
  WHERE
  (i + @byStep) <= @toNumber
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE_NumbersTable
)
;
```

and

```
CREATE FUNCTION NumbersTable (
  @fromNumber int,
  @toNumber int
) RETURNS TABLE
RETURN (
WITH T_0_THRU_15 AS (
SELECT 0 j UNION ALL
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 6 UNION ALL
SELECT 7 UNION ALL
SELECT 8 UNION ALL
SELECT 9 UNION ALL
SELECT 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 11 UNION ALL
SELECT 12 UNION ALL
SELECT 13 UNION ALL
SELECT 14 UNION ALL
SELECT 15 
)
SELECT T1.j + (T2.j*16) + (T3.j*256) + @fromNumber i
FROM   T_0_THRU_15 T1, T_0_THRU_15 T2, T_0_THRU_15 T3
WHERE T1.j + (T2.j*16) + (T3.j*256) + @fromNumber <= @toNumber
)
;
```

I am running this against Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. The strange thing is that I believe I have run this code against this database before and it worked and I simply don't know what to do now.

Comment: Is NumbersTable not a t SQL function? I had assumed it was.

Comment: Thanks to whomever pointed out that NumbersTable is not a standard TSQL function. I'm good with ANSI SQL, but never learned DB specific stuff.

Comment: Why do you have TWO different `CREATE FUNCTION`s here? Is the function different in two different databases?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sorry, I'm wrong person to ask. My guess was the two different parameter sets. Again, I'm not the guy that does this stuff.

Comment: @Thom sequence generators will be in Denali

Comment: @Hogan Um, the national park? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: No, there is no such thing as overloading. Can you explain exactly where you got these two `CREATE FUNCTION` statements?

Comment: @Thom  Denali is the next version of SQL Server, then your assumption - "Is NumbersTable not a t SQL function? I had assumed it was", will be true

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'll try. We have a main software application and a companion software application. The main app has been re-written. The companion software is slated to be re-written. In the meantime, there was a deadline to deliver the main app and companion app, so a DB developer wrote a bunch of views to make the companion app work on the main app. We have a stack of SQL scripts that we run when we create the database and these to create functions are in separate SQL files that get run on creation.

Comment: @Hogan to be fair, a `SEQUENCE` in SQL Server 2012 is not the same thing as the sequence generator these TVFs provide. If you call this TVF three times with the same parameters, you get hte same sequence values, whereas a `SEQUENCE` will only give you 1-100 once, the next time it will be 101-200. And it is not all that simple to get a range like that, have you tried this at all? The built-in procedure provides `SQL_VARIANT` as output and it is a real pain to work with.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Sadly I haven't tried 2012.  Basing my comment on an article I read a while ago (can't remember where), the author claimed these kind of patterns would not be needed with sequence support in 2012.  Bummer to hear this might not be true.

Comment: @Hogan I wrote an article about this you might find useful: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/11/11/sql-server-11-denali-using-sequence.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumbersTable is probably a [table valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Try this:

```
select cast(cast(getdate() + i as date) as datetime) DATEVALUE  
from dbo.NumbersTable(1,100,1)
```

It probably means "return the values from 1 to 100 in increments of 1".

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d2b6/1)

Comment: Couldn't get this to work b/c that function hasn't been created in the DB, yet. It's only getting created in the loader when everything gets built.

Comment: So create the function then! I updated my answer with a SQL Fiddle example.

Comment: Thanks for that, I couldn't get the create to run and then I realized it was b/c of a blank line.

Comment: It returns a selection of dates for the next 100 days.

Answer (score 1):

Check the code for the `NumbersTable` function or stored procedure.  This will show you how many parameters it will accept.

The error is telling you that you are passing in too many parameters.

```
from NumbersTable(1,100,1)
```

Based on the code for the `NumbersTable` you will adjust the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> Here are the function create**s** for NumbersTable:

SQL Server does not allow function overloading; only one of the `CREATE FUNCTION`s you list will be the actual definition in the database in question. Judging from the error message, I'd say the code you're trying to use is expecting the three-parameter one, but in fact the database you're in has the two-parameter version.

The lesson is, don't do major upgrades while your chief database programmer is on vacation...

Comment: Yeah, tell my Project Manager that. :)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to return the next 100 days, why not create a function that does that? This will take any date, and any number of days (up to about 7000), and return a list of dates:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GenerateDaySequence
(
  @StartDate DATE,
  @NumDays   INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    SELECT TOP (@NumDays) 
      d = DATEADD(DAY,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])-1, 
      @StartDate)
    FROM sys.all_columns AS s1
  );
GO
```

Sample usage:

```
SELECT d FROM dbo.GenerateDaySequence(GETDATE(), 100);
```

Results:

```
d 
----------
2012-07-10
2012-07-11
...
2012-10-16
2012-10-17
```

Comment: Again, not the database developer.

Comment: @Thom my point is this is a suggestion you can pass along to the database people. You're asking a database question, I hope you don't expect anything but database answers.

Comment: Of course, you're just saying things that are not in my realm of expertise. I will pass along.